# Condicionar inserción de datos en estructuras, en C

Tags: c

Necesito llenar un estructura con una condición, que es: cuando yo ingrese un peso negativo o mi recorrido sea mayor a 3000, deje de pedirme que ingrese más datos. Acá dejo algo de lo que he hecho, pero no logro realizar la condición:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM  2000
struct comercio{
    int codigo;
    char entrega;
    float peso;
    float recorrido;
};

void lleratoscomercio(struct comercio *Objcomercio);
void promediodelpeso(struct comercio *Objcomercio);
void recorridodistancia(struct comercio *Objcomercio);
void formaentregas(struct comercio *Objcomercio);
void recudototal(struct comercio *Objcomercio);
int main()
{
    char elem [50];
    struct comercio micomercio[TAM], *ptrcomercio;
    ptrcomercio=&micomercio[0];
    lleratoscomercio(ptrcomercio);


    //return 0;
}
void lleratoscomercio(struct comercio *Objcomercio){
int i;
int cont=0;


    while(Objcomercio->peso < 0 || Objcomercio->recorrido<3000){
        printf("ingrese el codigo %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&Objcomercio->codigo);

        printf("ingrese el tipo de entrega desiganado por una sola letra:");
        scanf("%s",&Objcomercio->entrega);

        printf("ingrese el peso:");
        scanf("%f",&Objcomercio->peso);

        printf("ingrese el recorrido:");
        scanf("%d",&Objcomercio->recorrido);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada te señalo un pequeño detalle, `recorrido` es de tipo **float** y lo escaneas como tipo **%d**, entero, cuando debería se flotante:

```
scanf("%f", &Objcomercio->recorrido);
```

Ahora, para la condición yo lo haría con un `do{...}while(...)` para poder permitir por lo menos el ingreso de los datos por lo menos una vez y así evaluar la condición. Aquí te dejo una forma fácil de realizarlo:

```
int main()
{
    char elem [50];
    struct comercio micomercio[TAM];
    lleratoscomercio(micomercio);


    return 0;
}
void lleratoscomercio(struct comercio *Objcomercio){
    int i;
    int cont=0;


    do{
        printf("ingrese el codigo %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &Objcomercio[i].codigo);

        printf("ingrese el tipo de entrega desiganado por una sola letra:");
        scanf("%s", &Objcomercio[i].entrega);

        printf("ingrese el peso:");
        scanf("%f", &Objcomercio[i].peso);

        printf("ingrese el recorrido:");
        scanf("%f", &Objcomercio[i].recorrido);

        i++;
    }while(Objcomercio[i-1].peso > 0 && Objcomercio[i-1].recorrido < 3000);

    for(int j = 0;  j < i; j++){
        printf("%d\n", Objcomercio[j].codigo);
    }

}
```

Realizé algunos cambios:

- Mandé directamente a la función el array  `struct micomercio` y así usarlo como arreglo.
- Utilizé un ciclo **do while** para la condición, en la que la cambié a **AND**, así en caso de que no se cumpla alguna de las dos (con peso < 0 ó recorrido > 3000) el ciclo termina.

Bueno, espero te sirva de algo, saludos.